# Windows Phone 8 Databound App and back button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I've something that I can't get myself understand. I'm making an app with databound template. I put a textbox on mainpage and a button. when i type something in textbox and press on button it navigates to the listing page and that content comes from web and then if i press on back button and make a new search the results from previous search stays there. how can i reset/clear or disable cache of that page?

Comment: Are you saying the "ResultsPage" (second page) is cached or MainPage is cached?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could post your XAML and code-behind, but I will attempt to make a jab at an answer.  Where are you referencing the call to get the data from the web?  If it is in the constructor of the page, then that is why the previous search stays there.  What is probably happening is the first search constructs the secondary page, does your web call, and binds your data to the page.  Then when you press the back button, and click it again, the page is already constructed, so it uses the same data.

It is probably wise to call your web service in the OnNavigatedTo override method.  From the first page, you can pass parameters to your secondary page (i.e., pass the search term, then pass the search term into your web service).

Here is an example of passing parameters between pages: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Passing_parameters_while_navigating_between_pages_on_Windows_Phone

Also, make sure your Data Context for the second page is appropriately set each time the page is navigated to, since you have a data bound application.

Without code, I can't really help other than giving these things to think about.